# Apply XSL to External XML

Tags: xml, xslt

Currently I use:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="XSL.xsl"?>
```

To link XSL to XML.

If my xml was here: www.externaldomain.com/rss.xml (Outside of my domain) how can i get the XSL linked to the XML?

Can i point the XSL to a File or Link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't achieve this with "pure" xml+xslt(*).  Some external code will need to identify the xml and the xslt which should transform it.

Since you seem to be transforming XML, I'm going to guess you're doing this in the webbrowser.

You can do this using javascript, as [demonstrated on w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_client.asp).  However, cross-domain restrictions still apply if you're doing javascript-based requests (i.e. AJAX/XHR): if the originating server doesn't set the appropriate CORS headers to allow cross-domain javascript access, you'll need to proxy that xml request via your own server.

(*): [Mad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1484229/42921) uses entity references to cleverly embed external xml in a containing document.  It's definitely worth a try, but be aware that this kind of entity-based inclusion has been used in several information-disclosure leaks, which is why it's often not enabled in the xml parser (in particular, this shouldn't be able to subvert CORS in a browser).  You'll just have to try it in your situation.

Comment: This wont work, he clearly asked for a solution when the xml is "Outside of my domain". Javascript doesn't do cross domain. Why he upvoted your answer is beyond me as it's clearly 100% wrong and I only realized that after spending 20 min trying to get that example to work... In fact I cant think of a single time when that example would have any use,  it only works on files that are on the same domain, which can already be edited... So basically what I'm trying to say is, that is wrong, and I downvoted you for it.

Comment: @Cody: Sorry for your frustration, I'll update the answer to highlight the requirement for CORS.  If the originating site supports CORS, you likely can do this in javascript; otherwise you need to proxy the XML.

Comment: @Cody: I used to be an operator for a company and we were doing some procedures. To know if we can go on we could use an XML file that was populated by a partner organisation but we had no access to it and it was no question to ask them to change anything in it. We were waiting for a few specific informations to be here and the file was very long. We would love to display only the content of that specific tags.
Therefore we are in this situation where one needs to apply XSL to an external XML file.
Regards.

Answer (score 14):

**You can create a local XML file that includes the XML content of the remote XML file through an entity reference**.

The example below will give you the content of the remote XML file inside of a *wrapper* document element.

Then you can include a stylesheet processing instruction on your local XML file.

However, since the local file has a *wrapper* document element, you might need to point to a "wrapper XSLT" that uses **xsl:import** to import the original XSL.xsl and **apply-templates** starting with the content inside the *wrapper* element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE wrapper [
<!ENTITY content SYSTEM "http://stackoverflow.com/feeds">
]>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="XSL.xsl" ?>
<wrapper>
    &content;
</wrapper>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to run the XSLT inside .NET, you can easily use the XslCompiledTransform class in .NET to achieve this.

If you're trying to run this on e.g. the command line, there's a bunch of tools you can use to apply a XSLT file to a given XML file - typically however one that's on your local harddisk.

See e.g. Oleg Tkachenko's web site for [info on NXSLT](http://www.tkachenko.com/blog/archives/000722.html) and this other XSLT tools, or see this [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/xmlTransformer.aspx) for a Windows shell extension to apply a XSLT to a given XML file (on your local harddisk).

Hope this helps a bit.

Marc

Answer (score 2):

You could write a local xml file as wrapper:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="XSL.xsl" ?>
<wrapper Source="http://www.externaldomain.com/rss.xml"/>
```

And extend your stylesheet so that it understands the wrapper:

```
<xsl:template match="wrapper">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="document(./@Source)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

I haven't tested it with XML files over http but it works with local XML files that I don't want to change to include a xml-stylesheet processing instruction. It works mit Firefox, Opera and IE (7, I haven't tried other versions)

Answer (score 0):

One solution:
Get the external XML into an XMLDocument object and then insert a node that contains include statement of xsl.  Include xsl can be taken from http://adityabajaj.com/weblog/include-xsl-in-x-ml/.