# XSL: Converting External XML to readable XML

Tags: xml, xslt

a lot of my question was covered here, but I was left with a few additional problems: [Apply XSL to External XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483759/apply-xsl-to-external-xml)

Here is the XML and XSL I am using:

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="http://image1.frequency.com/xslt/sample.xslt" ?>
<wrapper Source="http://image1.frequency.com/xml/externalxml.xml"/>
```

External XML

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" xmlns:gazeebo="http://www.vimond.com/vimondFeedExtension/1.0" xmlns:machinima="http://xml.machinima.com/fields" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:plmedia="http://xml.theplatform.com/media/data/Media">
   <title>Feed</title>
   <updated>2016-05-25T00:53:54Z</updated>
   <entry>
      <id>guid</id>
      <title>Video Title</title>
      <content type="text">Description Text</content>
      <gazeebo:metadata name="description-short">Description Text</gazeebo:metadata>
      <gazeebo:metadata name="description-long" />
      <updated>2016-05-24T20:52:24Z</updated>
      <gazeebo:metadata name="episode">2153</gazeebo:metadata>
      <gazeebo:metadata name="genre">news</gazeebo:metadata>
      <gazeebo:metadata name="parental-guidance">TV-14</gazeebo:metadata>
      <gazeebo:metadata name="season">2</gazeebo:metadata>
      <gazeebo:metadata name="title" />
      <gazeebo:metadata name="hd">HD</gazeebo:metadata>
      <gazeebo:metadata name="actors">Actors</gazeebo:metadata>
      <gazeebo:metadata name="asset-length">192</gazeebo:metadata>
      <gazeebo:metadata name="director">Director</gazeebo:metadata>
      <gazeebo:metadata name="tags">uncharted</gazeebo:metadata>
      <gazeebo:metadata name="original-air-date">2016-05-23</gazeebo:metadata>
      <media:group>
         <media:thumbnail url="https://internal-dist.s3.amazonaws.com/s3.jpg" />
         <media:content url="http://link.theplatform.com/media&amp;format=redirect" type="video/mpeg" />
         <dcterms:valid>start=2016-05-27T07:00:00Z;end=2016-12-12T07:00:00Z;scheme=W3C-DTF</dcterms:valid>
      </media:group>
   </entry>
</feed>
```

XSLT

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >

<xsl:template match="wrapper">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="document(./@Source)"/>
</xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="entry/id">
        <CD-NAME><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></CD-NAME>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="entry">
        <CATALOG-NAME><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></CATALOG-NAME>
    </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I run them through this tool:  xslttest.appspot.com , I get the output I want (changing over Entry over to Item)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed>
   <title>Feed</title>
   <updated>2016-05-25T00:53:54Z</updated>
   <item>
      <id>guid</id>
      <title>Test Title</title>
      <content type="text">Description Text</content>
      <metadata name="description-short">Description Text</metadata>
      <metadata name="description-long"/>
      <updated>2016-05-24T20:52:24Z</updated>
      <metadata name="episode">2153</metadata>
      <metadata name="genre">news</metadata>
      <metadata name="parental-guidance">TV-14</metadata>
      <metadata name="season">2</metadata>
      <metadata name="title"/>
      <metadata name="hd">HD</metadata>
      <metadata name="actors">Actor</metadata>
      <metadata name="asset-length">192</metadata>
      <metadata name="director">Director</metadata>
      <metadata name="tags">uncharted</metadata>
      <metadata name="original-air-date">2016-05-23</metadata>
      <group>
         <thumbnail url="https://internal-dist.s3.amazonaws.com/s3.jpg"/>
         <content url="http://link.theplatform.com/media&amp;format=redirect"
                  type="video/mpeg"/>
         <valid>start=2016-05-27T07:00:00Z;end=2016-12-12T07:00:00Z;scheme=W3C-DTF</valid>
      </group>
   </item>
</feed>
```

HOWEVER, when I actually look at the page, it doesn't appear to be readable.  It renders as text, and skips out all the nodes, and if I inspect source, it only shows the wrapper, so I think I'm unable to parse it?

When I look at the page it appears like this (renders as text):
http://image1.frequency.com/wrapper-test3.xml

So, the long and short of it, how can I get the nodes to show up on the page?  It's weird it shows up on that tool correctly, but when I try to view a page with this hosted, it doesn't work right.  Is there another way i.e. exporting the correct outcome to another doc that actually has it in the view-source correctly?  I need a parser to look at all the tags on the page, which is why I'm transforming XML to XML in the first place, so it can match my specs.

Any help would be appreciated.  I would be willing to use another technology as well, like copying the document with JS and putting it to another page.  I simply need to transform XML to a more usable form, its seemingly simple.

Comment: please specify "that tool" where you say it works and specify on what tool/browser? it does not work. My first suggestion would be to add an `<xsl:output method="xml"/>` as second line in the xsl, though that sould not matter. Other option would be to check the browser? console if it complains on something.

Comment: Oops, I meant to include the link to what I was using to test: http://xslttest.appspot.com/

Comment: If you want to say that it works in xslttest but doesn't in appspot.com then please say so (or vice versa), even from you comment I cannot guess it. Also add other relevant information that one might come up to question... It is always easier to see all than to have to ask back for every inch of information

Comment: If you put my XML and XSLT in the original post into  xslttest.appspot.com , the output appears to be what I want, but when I put that same  XSLT in practice, it properly uses a wrapper to grab the text from an external source, but it doesn't render it properly, just spitting out all element values continuously.  I need a properly formed XML document: http://image1.frequency.com/xml/wrapper-test.xml

EDIT:  Okay, I see it renders differently on Firefox than on Chrome.  Chrome it spits out an error. error on line 1 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document

I'll work on a fix.

Comment: *please* edit the question so that anyone stumbling here can see what it's about without having to read ten comments...